# count top most frequent phrases in a text column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, frequency, phrase

I have a pandas dataframe with a text column which has 50 phrases for each record separated by "|" and i want to count the top 50 phrases in the whole data. for example consider the column "text" in data has 4 phrases in each row separated by a pipe. (real data has 50 phrases). Space before and after pipe.

```
                                        text
       0    "Andy | max min | tea | pal"
       1    "no limit | toy 2011 | hess | mix"
       2    "Andy | Andy | toy 2011| pal"
```

how can i find the top n features? For example in the above the top 3 phrases are:

```
 Andy       3
 toy 2011   2
 pal        2
```

Comment: example show only 4 on each row, and is there spaces next to | or not?

Comment: @ Christian Sloper it is example only real data has 50 phrases and yes there is space before and after pipe

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
from collections import Counter
# df["text"] = df["text"].str.split(" | ")
df["text"] = df["text"].apply(lambda x: [s.strip() for s in x.split("|")])
c = Counter([item for row in df.text for item in row])
c.most_common(3)
[('Andy', 3), ('pal', 2), ('toy 2011', 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get your answer.

```
df['text'].str.lower().str.split('|').explode().str.strip().value_counts().nlargest(3)
```